# Google Analytics MCF - how is sampling done?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

According to the Google [sampling documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192), sampling is done based on sessions (fact). In Google MCF queries, sessions [are not available](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/) as a metric or dimension (fact?) Now I wonder: how is sampling done if there is no metric or dimension for sessions (and date)?

I suspect that sampling for Google MCF is done based on a maximum number of rows of 10.000 for each query. Are there more than 10.000 results? Than sampling is true. Is this correct?

Use-case: let's say I make a query and the "TotalResults" are 67540. Does this mean that I can get all the unsampled data with querying 7 calls (6x10000 and one time 7540 rows)? How do I know which dateranges to query than?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried some different approached and found out that the sampling is doe based on sessions and dates, same as the other data from the API.